# office 365 Set-Credential

Tags: office365

How I could set the credentials from my script, it's annoying to keep entering my user and password every time while development.

Basically I'm looking some function like Set-Credential.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
$cred = Get-Credential
$O365 = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
$importcmd = Import-PSSession $O365
$importcmd.ExportedFunctions.Count
```

Or you can use this script - something like that:

```
$domain=YOUR_DOMAIN
$userName = "YOUR_LOGIN@$domain.onmicrosoft.com"  ($domain change to your domain)
$password = "PASSWORD"  
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force  
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $securePassword  
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session


$User = “<user@domain.com>”
$Pass = “<password>”
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($User,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force))
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $Cred
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```